# Maven release from a branch by jenkins

Tags: maven, svn, jenkins, version, maven-release-plugin

I have to perform a maven release from branch with Jenkis and tag the RELEASE.At the same time, i need to update the version (new SNAPSHOT) on trunk.

For Example:

> **/trunk**  contains **Module_1.0.0-SNAPSHOT**
>
> **/branches/Module_1.0.0-SNAPSHOT**

After Perform Maven Release on **/branches/Module_1.0.0-SNAPSHOT**

> **/trunk**  contains **Module_1.0.1-SNAPSHOT**
>
> **/tag/Module_1.0.0-RELEASE**

Setting maven-release-plugin and *scm (url, connection, developerConnection)*, **/tag/Module_1.0.0-RELEASE** and new version on branch go right way.

But, even with *developerConnection* pointing to trunk doesn't udpate the version on trunk.

How could I achieve that?
thank's in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run the Maven release plugin on your branch (/branches/Module_1.0.0-SNAPSHOT), it will:

- Update the version number on this branch (1.0.0-SNAPSHOT --> 1.0.0)
- Apply a tag on this branch (tag/1.0.0 or something like that)
- Move your branch to 1.0.1-SNAPSHOT

Even if you set the developerConnection property, the Maven release plugin will not update the version number of your trunk branch.

If you want to increase the version number on the trunk, you have to release from the trunk (or release from the branch + merge your branch to your trunk).

Comment: Thank's a lot, Bruno. Me too, i've just verified that is not possible to release from the branch and automatically update the version number on the trunk. I'll try to release from branch and attach a post-relase script that performs the merge branch to the trunk.